# Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined,var data = { "email": User.Identity.Email()}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sendmessage

i want to usse ajax and send email for data but i have error Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined
code:
var email = User.Identity.Email();

[image]

Comment: `User` is likely a server-side object. You need to wrap it in quotes and use the `@` symbol to get its value to client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

how does the `User` object look like?
where did you define it?

its maybe a scope problem, where have you defined the variable named `User`?
maybe the `User` object is not accessible inside the click function

just letting you know:

instead writng long object like this:
`{"email": email, "isEmail": false, "Token": token}`

you can write it like this:
`{email, "isEmail": false, token}`
(if the property name has the same variable name you can write like this)

more important thing don't use capital letter in object name its just an object not a class